# Generate a list of Sheets that meet a condition in Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to use Google App Script within Google Sheets to generate a list of sheet names that meet the condition of having a "Y" in a set cell across each sheet. A pseudocode example I thought about was:

```
>look through all sheets
>if cell "V2" on that sheet contains "Y", add the sheet's name to a list
>return the list
```

I just can't get my head around many of the functions in the App scripts.

Answer (score 2):

```
function sheetNames() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var sA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    var sh=shts[i];
    if(String(sh.getRange('V2').getValue()).indexOf('Y')>-1) {
      sA.push(sh.getName());
    }
  }
  return sA;
}
```